# Offset text without moving background

Tags: html, css

Is it possible—without adding an extra wrapper element—to offset the position of text in an HTML element *without* causing the background to also shift?

Motivation:

I have existing HTML markup (phpBB) and I'm styling some links to look like buttons so that they are visibly pushed down when `:active` (mouse button down). I have half of this working via a background change, but I want to also offset the text down and to the right 1 pixel.

Existing HTML markup (cannot be changed):

```
<a href="…"><span></span>Hello World</a>
```

Fiddle showing the effect and existing CSS (which can be changed): http://jsfiddle.net/szxPz/1/

***Edit**: I can get the text to move to the right with `text-indent:1px; margin-right:-1px`, but that still leaves the need to move the text down as well.*

Comment: If it's a fixed height, can you not take it down a pixel and add padding-top: 1px ? You'll need to render it as a block or inline-block though I'd imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that by increasing the `padding-top` and decreasing the `height` by 1.

Comment: Spot on; how silly of me not to think of it. I see a large number of updates on the JSFiddle; were you planning on elaborating on your answer?